# Meaning in context of "to fold something together"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

> “Add the option -f **to fold upper and lower case together**, so that case
>   distinctions are not made during sorting; for example, a and A compare
>   equal.”
>
> Excerpt From: Brian W. Kernighan. “The C Programming Language, Second
>   Edition.

I am not sure what this means exactly. I was thinking about two options:

- convert all uppercase to lowercase letters or vice versa
- keep the cases as they are and merely treat them as equal

Does the expression *to fold something together*  in this case have a specific meaning?
 Or am I free to choose an interpretation?

Comment: The clause *so that case distinctions are not made during sorting; for example, a and A compare equal* defines what *folding* means here.

Comment: So merely treat them as if they were equal, but not turning them into equal? I am not sure if I am understood. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Correct.  Treat them as equal but do not change them.  Thus, the set: { BB,ba,aB,cA,Cb,Aa,CC,ac} would sort to: {Aa,aB,ac,ba,BB,cA,Cb,CC} and not {ac,aB,ba,ca,Aa,BB,Cb,CC}.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from an [exercise](http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_5.15_sortfnr.html) in C programming, in which the student is asked to modify a line sorting program.  "Fold together" here means to treat each lower-case letter and its corresponding upper-case letter as the same value for purposes of the sort.

Comment: So merely treat them as if they were equal, but not turning them into equal? I am not sure if I am understood. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I think so.  The program sorts the lines as though all uppercase letters were lowercase letters but outputs the lines unchanged.

Comment: Yes, "fold" was an unfortunately poetic choice of words, especially for a manual, because it implies action where there is no action. The only action is the reordering of the entries.